# Lifting local compactness in covering spaces

Tags: general-topology

Since the total space of a cover is locally homeomorphic to the base space, local topological properties (like local (path) connectedness, T<sub>1</sub> etc.) lift from the base space to the total space. The same holds for local compactness, if we assume the base space is Hausdorff.

My question is, given a non-Hausdorff locally compact space $X$, must every cover of $X$ be locally compact.

My intuition says no, because the compact neighbourhoods in $X$ might be too big to be "seen" by the covering structure. I can't think of any counterexamples, mainly because I don't remember any non-compact non-Hausdorff spaces right now and won't have access to Steen & Seebach for a couple of days. Although, when writing this, it strikes me that there could be conditions on $X$, which would ensure that the covering projection is a proper map, in which case we would be done.

NB: By a locally compact space I mean a space in which every point has a compact neighbourhood.

Edit: Thinking further, if the base space is T<sub>3</sub>/regular (the weaker of the two, whatever your convention might me) and locally compact every cover is locally compact, basically for the same reason as in the Hausdorff case.

Comment: Have you tried making a "non-locally compact circle" and then mimicked the covering of the circle by the line? Here your "non-locally compact circle" might be something like the rational points on a circle, or some other bizarre creature.

Comment: @wckronholm I think you misunderstood me. I want the base space to be locally compact and not Hausdorff (looking at it, the phrasing might be a bit confusing).

I've been thinking that the one-point compactification of the rationals might provide a counterexample. As far as I know, there are theorems characterizing the homeomorphic type of the rationals, from which it should be possible to construct an appropriate cover.

Comment: @Miha you're right. I've had this question of yours running around the back of my head for a few days, and it got a bit jumbled up.
Have you had any luck constructing a cover of $\mathbb{Q}^+$?

Comment: @wckronholm Maybe something like this could work: pick a proper neighbourhood $U$ of $\infty$ in $\mathbb{Q}^+$. Then take as the total space $\mathbb{Q}^*\times\{1/n;n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup U\times 0$ with the obvious projection. I'm almost sure this is a covering space. I think it isn't locally compact on the 0-th level, but I'm not so sure about that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you should try posting this question to mathoverflow, since it seems to be of sufficient difficulty?

Comment: I did. It hasn't attracted much interest though.

Comment: Yes, it might be too big. But when one gets a compact on _X_ that contains a neighborhood, one can construct its cover by such open sets that are homeomorphic to open sets on the covering space, and then select a finite subcover. Wouldn’t it be a way to construct a compact on the covering space that contains a neighborhood?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I don't really see what you're getting at. Sure you might lift a particular cover but how do you lift the compact itself? If the cover is finite I guess you can just take the total lift, but what if it's not?

Comment: @Miha Habič: possibly speaking about finite **preimage**, not finite cover; or did I miss something?

Comment: See the answer on mathoverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67181/lifting-local-compactness-to-a-covering-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this question was subsequently asked on MathOverflow. It was answered there by Taras Banakh ([see his answer there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/287202/1058)), so I am writing this answer to close this version as well.